# iOS: How to avoid/disable default call alert?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am developing an iOS app with swift, I will explain how my App works.

The app will connect to a PC client With TCP/IP 
And will receive a phone number to dial 
When I am trying to send The number to the app to make a call the phone showing an Alert with 2 buttons `Call` and `Cancel`.

**Is there any way to avoid/disable default call alert?**

> **Note:** the User know that's my app will make a call and I will have an
>   agreement from the user

Comment: You don't want to see notification popup when call request sent ?

Comment: I’d say no and for a very good reason, it would be a pretty big security risk if your phone just went ahead and dialled numbers.

Comment: @DarshanPatel  yes Like that

Comment: @Lee I don't think Its a good reason we have the same app done on Android and we care About the Agreement Of the User So our application will not make any risk

Comment: I think it’s a VERY good reason. I wouldn’t want an app just making phone calls without me having to approve it. That’s just really bad practice.

Comment: the Idea is The user will click a phone number On Windows App then his Phone will call this number so already he made approval for it

Comment: The problem is your app isn't the only one and so Apple are not going to give all apps this kind of permission.  While you may have an agreement with your user what about apps that don't and could just decide to dial a premium rate number without informing the user.  This functionality is not going to be possible in iOS and that's a good thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Is there any way to avoid/disable the default call alerts?**

> Unfortunately, There is no provision to avoid/disable it. We can not control the
> system generated alert. I tried the same thing a few months back
> but no luck. Still, there is no solution to avoid it.

Thanks

Comment: And in future there will never be a solution for it as far I know the apple. This would be a privacy breach if call is made without asking the user. Not sure in which version this was introduced but it was possible before that